# Designing Raspberry Pi Compute Module with Ethernet capability

Tags: ethernet, modules

I recently got the new Raspberry Pi Compute Module due to the small size and ability to create custom board attaching with it.

The application requirement I need is just USB, some I/Os and LAN.

I realised the module development kit doesn't not come with Ethernet capability. I need LAN to create a client/server secure connection through the Pi.

Anyone can share info resources on how to make this compute module ethernet capable? any schematics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Broadcom BCM2835 does not have on-board ethernet so just like the standard raspberry pi you will need to add ethernet via USB. On the B/B+ the ethernet was provided via the LAN9512 USB hub/ethernet chip.

So for the compute module development board you can just get a compatible USB ethernet adapter.

For a device built around the compute module you might want to look at something like the LAN9512 or LAN9514.

You could look at the [schematics published by the Raspberry Pi Foundation](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Raspberry-Pi-Schematics-R1.0.pdf) to see how they did it.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the [ENC28J60](http://digipak.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/p-184-ENC28j60-Ethernet-Interface-Module1.jpg) Module, which is only a few dollars from the usual places - ebay, aliexpress etc, and won't consume your USB port.

To do this, wire things up:

```
Pi            ENC28J60
----------------------
+3V3          VCC
GND           GND
GPIO8         CS
GPIO9/MISO    SO
GPIO10/MOSI   SI
GPIO11/SCLK   SCK
GPIO25        NT
```

Now, with your pi booted, open up '/boot/config.txt':

```
sudo vi /boot/config.txt
```

Towards the end of the file, add:

```
dtoverlay=enc28j60
```

Now reboot your pi, and bask in the pleasures of network.

This is described in more detail on the [RaspberryPi website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cm-peri-sw-guide.md).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have two questions about this chip: 1. will the raspberry pi drive set the half-duplex/full-duplex register for me regardless of how I wire LEDB? 2. Can I configure it to use a different chip select / SPI interface in case I want to use an SPI WiFi chip too?

Answer (score 1):

Compute module 4 has an on-board ethenet PHY simplfing matters so you only need to add a magjack (or separate transformers and jack) to your carrier board.