# Adding a LAN module to Compute Module 3

Tags: compute-module

For an alarm with wired sensors and home automation purposes, I want to use a compute module 3 (for its eMMC reliability) but I have an issue ; I need a LAN connection.

[In one of your answers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26061/designing-raspberry-pi-compute-module-with-ethernet-capability/107389#107389) 
Eliette suggest to use an enc28j60 module but I already own a WIZ850io and prefer this module.

1. Does the driver exist ?
2. Is it possible to add "dtoverlay=w5500" in
       the config.txt ?

Comment: You can find on standard overlays on Raspbian: /boot/overlays/README. And did you google for your module name/id + 'raspberry pi'? BTW: others have added  LAN9514 module (same one as used on several Pi models)

Answer (score 1):

> Does the driver exist ?

Yes, there is a [driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/ethernet/wiznet) which was mainlined in version 5.3. Raspbian is currently using version 4.19, so you'll have to wait or build the driver yourself. Running [`rpi-update`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/updating.md) is also worth a try, judging by the github they are already testing version 5.5.

> Is it possible to add "dtoverlay=w5500" in the config.txt ?

You'll have to write the overlay file first. It's still the same "Ethernet over SPI" inteface as ENC28J60, so I'd take the enc28j60 overlay as a starting point. Maybe it will even work as is.

Answer (score 1):

As of bump to 4.19.80 the w5500 driver exists, at least for SPI0.

I did a short test with RPi Zero (Buster lite) and everything performed as expected.

Name:   w5500

Info:   Overlay for the Wiznet W5500 Ethernet Controller on SPI0

Load:   `dtoverlay=w5500,<param>=<val>`

Params:

- int_pin: GPIO used for INT (default 25)
- speed: SPI bus speed (default 30000000)
- cs: SPI bus Chip Select (default 0)

https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot/overlays

You will probably want to assign it some kind of a static MAC address though.

Comment: How to assign MAC? I tried this but it's not working